# Open Anaconda Python with a script

Tags: 18.04, python

Oftentimes I need Python to do quick calculations. Each time I want to use Python for a few basic things, I have to open the terminal, run Python, import libraries, and define constants.

On my Windows machine, I save time using a batch file that opens Python in interactive mode, imports the math package, and defines things (like `Na = 6.022e23`). Here's the script:

```
@echo off
rem = r'''
python -ix "%~f0" %*
exit /b
'''

#Embedded Python code starts here
del rem

import math

c = 299792458
Na = 6.022e23
```

How do I translate this into an equivalent script (e.g. bash) that can be used in Ubuntu 18.04? Preferably one that I can add to my favorites and access via clicking the sidebar.

Comment: You could do that with a bash script - just translate your windows batch file to bash.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Any suggestions on how to do this with the above code (see recent edit of my original post)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to skin a cat.  Here's one of them

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 -ix -c "import math; c = 299792458; Na = 6.022E23"
```

And that's it.  The equivalent windows batch file is a one liner that contains just

```
@python -ix -c "import math; c = 299792458; Na = 6.022E23"
```

There is no need to create a python script and then execute it.  You can execute the commands using the -c option.  The @ just hides the command from being echoed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer.